# Matlab How to display a series of numbers from a vector as a string?

Tags: matlab

I know that num2str can be used like:

```
tested = 3.53;
X=[The mean of the data set is:', num2str(tested)];
disp(X);
Output: The mean of the data set is: 3.53
```

My question is how do I use a similar method to display a vector?
Essentially I have a vector given by `Concentration=[3.5, 3.8, 3.2, 3.9]` and would like to print out something along the lines of `"The concentrations of the data set are: 3.5, 3.8, 3.2, 3.9"`

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is:

```
disp(['The concentrations of the data set are: ' mat2str(Concentration)])
```

But it doesn't give the output you require:

```
The concentrations of the data set are: [3.5 3.8 3.2 3.9]
```

Here are two hacky options:

```
fprintf('The concentrations of the data set are: ')
fprintf('%.1f, ', Concentration)
fprintf('\b\b\n')
```

Output:

```
The concentrations of the data set are: 3.5, 3.8, 3.2, 3.9
```

Note that the middle `fprintf` works with any number of elements. The `\b\b` removes the trailing space and comma.

Also:

```
outstr = strrep(mat2str(Concentration), ' ', ', ')
disp(['The concentrations of the data set are: ' outstr(2:end-1)])
```

Output:

```
The concentrations of the data set are: 3.5, 3.8, 3.2, 3.9
```

Comment: mat2str is a great choice here! I think we don't reach for it often enough for formatting output as opposed to doing dynamic code generation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strjoin` to build the string and `fprintf` to include it in a sentence.

```
conc = [3.5, 3.8, 3.2, 3.9]; 
concStr = arrayfun( @num2str, conc, 'uni', 0 ); % convert to cell of chars

% Join all values with the separator ', ' and then use this single string with fprintf
fprintf( 'The concentrations of the data set are: %s', strjoin( concStr, ', ' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the new `compose()` function! It's like an array-oriented `sprintf()`.

```matlab
strjoin(compose("%0.2f", Concentration), ", ")
```

Gives you:

```
ans = 
    "3.50, 3.80, 3.20, 3.90"
```